# Facebook graph returns access-token error for one site, but not another

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think the root cause of this is my general misunderstanding of how the Facebook API works, so I hope someone with a bit more knowledge can point me in right direction.

All I'm trying to do is return a facebook gallery for one of our clients onto two different pages, hosted on different servers. I use this format on one page:

```
$albums = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebook_ID.'/albums') );
```

And this works fine, I get what I need. However, doing this on the other site gives me this error:

```
"message":"An access token is required to request this resource."
```

Does it really need an access token if all I am doing is requesting a public gallery? To further confuse me, if I simply put this in my browser:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/$facebook_ID/albums
```

I get all the required info. This tends me towards thinking it's not a domain issue?

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

Here's some more info with curl.

First - the request that works, from my local box:

```
* About to connect() to graph.facebook.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 69.171.242.27...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to graph.facebook.com (69.171.242.27) port 80 (#0)

> GET /370438539411/albums HTTP/1.1

> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0

> Host: graph.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< ETag: "2829e31bfef4b737cdb31aab0f73c8ad35826012"
< Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< X-FB-Rev: 801567
< X-FB-Debug: /uN6PrzpTWLLaJOn8vuww0ECYjineJN6P9w/DvvVczY=
< Date: Wed, 01 May 2013 12:01:26 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 35483
< 
ALL THE THINGS
```

And then here is the request from our live server - an EC2 instance ( if this is relevant )

```
* About to connect() to graph.facebook.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 173.252.101.26...   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time         Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
^M  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0connected
* Connected to graph.facebook.com (173.252.101.26) port 80 (#0)
> GET /370438539411/albums HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: graph.facebook.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "An access token is required     to request this resource."
< X-FB-Rev: 801567
< X-FB-Debug: wSxKF5MlCAmEFf2BuYRBDotWWreR6/t5m5mebc8vDXw=
< Date: Wed, 01 May 2013 12:03:38 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 112
< 
^M  0   112    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0{ [data not shown]
^M100   112  100   112    0     0    181      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   212
* Connection #0 to host graph.facebook.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104}}
(END)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some or the other thing that might make or break access to public data like they way you are accessing. As you have already experienced this, I would like you to go safe on this and instead create an App and use an **[App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/)** to query for the public data instead of going to it directly as Facebook might in near future even change this..

Comment: Sounds like that's what I might have to do. See above, the request I am sending is identical, looks like facebook want OAuth from EC2 though.

Comment: Yup, I tried finding out how was it working. Even on my system it was working within chrome but not through a REST query plugin within chrome. But even if it works now, Facebook might soon just change it.